# SQLite sort for varchar alphanumeric list

Tags: sqlite, sorting, varchar, alphanumeric

I'm writing a music program with SQLite as a back-end and I'm trying to work out how to sort all the albums in the order I want them. In theory, this is pretty easy but there's just the odd one I'm having trouble with as below.

Take these three albums - how to I get them sorted in this order when using SELECT DISTINCT Album FROM Album ORDER BY Album COLLATE NOCASE:

Now That's What I Call Music! 10
Now That's What I Call Music! 99
Now That's What I Call Music! 100

As opposed to what they get sorted in which is:

Now That's What I Call Music! 10
Now That's What I Call Music! 100
Now That's What I Call Music! 99

I want 100 to follow 99, if that makes sense.

Comment: The character '1' is less than the character '9', so any string starting with '1' is going to sort less than strings starting with '9'. When wanting to sort a string but with numbers in it sorted numerically instead of lexicographically, I usually just write my own collation function that understands the strings in question and throw it in an extension module that anything that needs to use the database can load.

Comment: Or have whatever program gets the list of titles from the db do the sorting instead, of course. That can be a lot easier if your queries allow for it (No `WHERE x < y` type stuff for example)

Answer (score 0):

Shawn has given you an explanation of what you see, and a possibility of getting what you desire by writing a custom collation function.

But do you **really** have albums with names like "Now That's What I Call Music! 10"?  My guess is the "10" is some sort of distinguishing code, in which case a better solution is to redesign your database schema to separate out the actual name from the distinguishing code, i.e., two separate columns.  That way you can sort on both fields like `ORDER BY Album_name, distinguishing code`.

(When you create the table you will also probably want the combination of the two fields to be unique, like `UNIQUE (Album_name, distinguishing_code)`)

Comment: Thank you to both of you. I think Shawn has got a good answer but I'll be honest, I'm not sure how to actually write a collation function. I'm not beyond a SQLite (or any SQL) basic user.

Comment: The database really does, however, contain album names such as Now That's What I Call Music! 10. This is the very popular NOW series (in the US, they currently only go to 66 but 100 in the UK). I have over 6000 albums of all sorts of names - not all have numerics, of course. But it is not distinguishing code in this instance, this is truly the number of the Now album in question. Other examples would be UK Number Ones 1996 and UK Number Ones 2002. However, 100 is the anomaly as there are very rarely over 100 albums in a series hence the problem (and the question).

Comment: In that case, probably a custom collation function is your best option.  You **could** also force the sorting by entering names like "Now That's What I Call Music!  10", with two spaces before the final number, but that forces you to manipulate the actual titles before entering them.  What language are you writing in?

Comment: I'm writing the software in VB.NET with a SQLite back-end. The software fills a tileset of album covers using the following:

Comment: sMusicTileAdd = "SELECT DISTINCT Album, AlbumArt, AlbumArtist, AlbumSortArtist, AlbumYear FROM Album ORDER BY AlbumSortArtist COLLATE NOCASE, Album COLLATE NOCASE

Comment: So I guess I'd need to write a collation function either before that statement or actually in the database itself? The software reads a music library so I can't really enter the names like NTWICM! 10 manually

Comment: You would have to create the collation function and register it after connecting to the database.  I'm not familiar with VB.NET, so I'm afraid I can't help you beyond that.